# Is it better to use strings.xml or just texts in layout files?

Tags: android, text

I’m developing an app with a lot of texts in it.

So, is it a better practice to grab all the texts of the app from a `strings.xml`, or can I just paste the texts in the layout files?

Answer (score 4):

Always use a `strings.xml` or similar localization file for your development. It will make life so much easier down the road.

Comment: Yes, for two reasons - one is localization. The other is you might want to use the same string in multiple places (for example, you might have a "settings" button in multiple activities). If you need to change the text it's easier to have one place you can change it for everything.

Comment: lint will nag at you if you put literals directly in your layouts.

Comment: yea I was thinking this way but wasn’t sure, thanks appreciate the answers

Comment: If it answers your question, would you mind marking it as such?